# ISO 8601 format from Unix timestamp in c?

Tags: c, date, unix, time, iso

I need to convert unix timestamp to ISO-8601 format like this

```
2018-01-23T03:04:19.703-05:00
```

I am using `strftime()` to create format like this

```
2018-01-23T03:04:19-0500
```

How can I convert this to the above format? Is there any library function to do that? Or I have to do it programmatically

Comment: Perhaps read the manual page for the function and work out the correct format http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

Comment: @EdHeal I saw that but can't able to figure out how to display like -05:00 or add microsecond after seconds field. like 19.703

Comment: Unix timestamps don't have fractions of seconds.

Comment: BTW, that's milliseconds, not microseconds.

Comment: You said in the question that you were able to create a format with `-0500`. Why do you now say that you haven't figured out how to do that? It's the `%z` format operator.

Comment: @Barmar  I want the format it like -05:00 and I am able to get -0500  using %z.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `strftime`. You'll have to modify the string after formatting it, and insert the `:`.

Comment: @Barmar the time format is from syslog that's why I was wondering if there is any library function that can do the conversion